# swap array values in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I want to shift left array values if my v=4 is in a[n],remove 4 from a[n] and at the end index add 0,how i can do this?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
const int n=5;
int main()
{

int a[n]={1,5,4,6,8}, v=4;
int b[n];

cout << "Enter a Value" << endl; 
cout<<v<<endl;

for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
 cout<<a[i];            
}
cout<<endl;
for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
    b[j]=a[j];
    if(a[j]==v)
    b[j]=a[++j];


  cout<<b[j];            
  }


 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: you are not taking input to `v`,  `if(a[j]=v)` should be `f(a[j]==v)`

Comment: `cout<<v<<endl;` performs output, not input.

Comment: `if(a[j]=v)` shouldn't it be `if(a[j]==v)`?

Comment: You also go out of bounds with `a[j+1]`

Comment: Consider using `std::array` or `std::vector` and the various useful functions in the `<algorithm>` header. If you're using C++, there's no need to muck about with C-style arrays in this situation.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Uh, no. Not in C++.

Comment: my code is not working,how I can remove 4 from array a[n]?

Comment: @KonradRudolph <cstring> _Not in C++_ Lie.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I know, so what? It’s terrible in C++ code. You can get almost any C code to work in C++ but that doesn’t mean it’s a good idea. C++ offers vastly superior tools.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY in C++ it's better practice to use std library functions like `std::copy` and `std::fill`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Just for the record, I didn’t claim that these functions didn’t exist in C++. “Not in C++” meant that you *should not use them* in C++.

Comment: @KonradRudolph The doubt also does not it should be used..Although understand your claim.

Comment: I have a sneaking suspicion that stuff like `memset` and `memmove` is likely to be rather more efficient than `std::whatever`, given that their use implies a contiguous buffer rather than abstract iterators that might point all over the process' address space. I'm too lazy to profile this, however.

Comment: @Rook This is definitely **not** the case. Modern standard library implementations are (for the most part) smart. If `std::copy` / `std::move` were slower than their C counterparts, they would be atrociously designed. In reality, in every modern standard library implementation they are completely on par, performance-wise (meaning they are **exactly** as efficient as their C counterpart, not one picosecond slower).

Comment: @Rook those containers that have continuous storage, have specializations that use `memmove()` internally.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I stand corrected! (though I'll let the picosecond timing comment slide...)

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <vector>       // needed for vector 
#include <algorithm>    // needed for find
#include <iostream>     // needed for cout, cin 

using namespace std;

// Vectors are just like dynamic arrays, you can resize vectors on the fly

vector<int> a { 1,5,4,6,8 };  // Prepare required vector
int v;

cout << "enter value";  // Read from user
cin >> v;

auto itr = find( a.begin(), a.end(), v);  // Search entire vector for 'v'
if( itr != a.end() ) // If value entered by user is found in vector
{
    a.erase(itr);    // Delete the element and shift everything after element
                     // Toward beginning of vector. This reduces vector size by 1
    a.push_back(0);  // Add 0 in the end. This increases vector size by 1
}

for( int i : a )     // Iterate through all element of a (i holds element)
    cout << i;       // Print i
cout << '\n';        // Line end
```

a few helpful links: 
[vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) , [find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/) , [iterator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/) , [erase](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/) , [push_back](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/)

Comment: @user2841243 then refer to the documentation of `std::vector` and `<algorithm>` header.

Comment: @MohitJain eh, *should be*; right now `boost::range` is a way to get that syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `std::rotate`. I suggest that you use `std::vector` instead of C arrays and take full advantage of the STL algorithms. Nevertheless, below I'm illustrating two versions one with C arrays and one with `std::vector`:

### Version with C array:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm> 

int main()
{
int const n = 5;
int a[n] = {1,5,4,6,8};
std::cout << "Enter a Value" << std::endl;
int v;
std::cin >> v;

for(auto i : a) std::cout << i<< " ";
std::cout << std::endl;

auto it = std::find(std::begin(a), std::end(a), v);
if(it != std::end(a)) {
  std::rotate(it + 1, it, std::end(a));
  a[n - 1] = 0;
}

for(auto i : a) std::cout << i<< " ";
std::cout << std::endl;

 return 0;
}
```

### Version with `vector`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm> 

int main()
{
std::vector<int> a{1,5,4,6,8};
std::cout << "Enter a Value" << std::endl;
int v;
std::cin >> v;

for(auto i : a) std::cout << i<< " ";
std::cout << std::endl;

auto it = std::find(std::begin(a), std::end(a), v);
if(it != std::end(a)) {
  std::rotate(it + 1, it, std::end(a));
  a.back() = 0;
}

for(auto i : a) std::cout << i<< " ";
std::cout << std::endl;

 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using `std::array`

```
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

// defines our array.
std::array<int, 5> a = {{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }};

// find the position of the element with the value 4.
auto where = std::find(a.begin(), a.end(), 4);

// if it wasn't found, give up
if (where == a.end())
  return 0;

// move every element past "where" down one.
std::move(where + 1, a.end(), where);

// fill the very last element of the array with zero
a[ a.size() - 1] = 0;

// loop over our array, printing it to stdout
for (int i : a)
  std::cout << i << " ";

std::cout << "\n";
```

Why would anyone use these awkward algorithms? Well, there are a few reasons. Firstly, they are container-independant. This will work with arrays and vectors and deques, no problem. Secondly, they can be easily used to work with a whole range of elements at once, not just single items, and can copy between containers and so on. They're also type-independant... you acn have an array of strings, or an vector of ints, or other more complex things, and the algorithms will still work just fine.

They're quite powerful, once you've got over their initial user-unfriendliness.

You can always use either `std::array` or `std::vector` or whatever without using the standard library algorithms, of course.

```
std::array<int, 5> a = {{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }};

size_t where = 0;
int to_remove = 4;

// scan through until we find our value.
while (a[where] != to_remove && where < a.size())
  where++;

// if we didn't find it, give up
if (where == a.size())
  return 0;

// shuffle down the values
for (size_t i = where; i < a.size() - 1; i++)
  a[i] = a[i + 1];

// set the last element to zero
a[ a.size() - 1] = 0;
```

As a final example, you can use `memmove` (as suggested by BLUEPIXY) to do the shuffling-down operation in one function call:

```
#include <cstring>

if (where < a.size() - 1)
  memmove(&a[where], &a[where + 1], a.size() - where);
```

Comment: You should **really** not use `memmove`, use [`std::move`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move) (or [`std::rotate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate)). Under the hood it’s the same but it has a safe C++ interface.